# Why am I getting 'cURL error 28: Resolving timed out' error on page refresh? getstream.io

Tags: php, curl, laravel-5, getstream-io

I keep getting a curl timeout using the stream-laravel library from getstream.io. It happens when I request an activity feed for display in a blade template.

I have the settings in stream-laravel config set to timeout at 3. When the page displays, it displays the activity feed correctly. If I refresh that page after the timeout, I get this curl error:

`cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 4058 milliseconds (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

What it seems like is going on, is that the curl session to getstream.io hasn't disconnected and when there is a page refresh, it thinks it's still connected and since the time has passed for the timeout, returns that error.

On a subsequent request (refresh of the page), it works again. Rinse and repeat.

I am not the only one to have had this issue, see: [GetStream.io connection timeout on PHP addActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36413620/getstream-io-connection-timeout-on-php-addactivity)

That issue was never resolved but is similar.

This is both on my local dev and in production.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, still waiting.